# How do I add the css class attribute to a textbox in razor?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have tried:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class='textbox'})
```

which isn't working.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class="textbox"})
```

A c# string literal does not take single quotes.

'textbox' -> "textbox"

Comment: You'r so right.. I blame it on the later hour... Shouldn't be coding in the middle of the night. Even the exception messages was telling me this (mayby in a more cryptic way)

Comment: For multiple classes e.g...
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class="textbox, anotherClass"})